# How do I multiply each number in a SASS list by a constant and output the results as a set of pixel values?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I am trying to do the following:

Include SASS mixins such as the following:

```
@include margin(1, 2, 4);
@include margin(5, 4);
```

And output the following in my compiled CSS:

```
margin: 8px 16px 32px
margin: 40px 32px
```

Basically, I want to take each argument provided, multiply it by 8, and add px to the end of it.

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function in sass

```
@mixin margin($number, $number2) {
  margin: $number $number2;
}

div {
   @include margin(multify8x(100px), multify8x(50px));
}
```

sass function available in sass 3.1.10. See the [document](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#Sass-based_Functions)

Comment: I was looking for a way were the function could take an unknown number of arguments

Comment: It seem sass doesn't support if else condition http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html